# Is there a way to specify subdomains that a cookie should be saved to? (rather than one, or all)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session-variables, session-cookies

I got my session variables being saved to all subdomains on my site via this:

```
Site::Application.config.session_store(
  :cookie_store, 
  :key => '_site_session',
  :domain => Settings.domain,
#  :secure => (Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging?), 
  :http_only => true)
```

where Settings.domain = '.site.com'

However, the way my site is setup, each account has their own subdomain. So this caused a big error since when someone logged in, they could enter any other subdomain and have access to that account (not all information, but some..weird).

So, what I want to do is allow people to share session variables with public subdomains (signin.site.com and signup.site.com) as well as their own personal subdomain (account1.site.com). However, those are the only ones that should be able to share it. Is there a way to specify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you handle logins on a subdomain like *signin.site.com*. It's not allowed to set the cookie for **.site.com* then.

Handling the authentication and setting the cookie from *http://site.com* should solve the problem.

Comment: site.com is already taken for my marketing page...but I guess I can try to put it at site.com/login. However, then the session won't persist from site.com to account1.site.com, because it is a different subdomain, and that is what I need. I was thinking of creating a before_filter in the application_controller to basically check that the current_account.subdomain == request.subdomain...but won't people be able to change their current_account info to get around that?

Comment: The cookie is served for account1.site.com as well when it has been set to .site.com. Ensure that you are not using www.site.com.

Comment: Sorry, i'm confused by this comment...what do you mean? I created a before_filter to check if the user is on the right account, is there any way to manipulate the session cookie (encrypted I believe) to try to access someone else's account?

Comment: What I mean is that if you log in your users at http://site.com/login (without www) the cookie should be valid for account1.site.com as well.

Comment: but then isn't the cookie available for account2.site.com also? that's the issue i'm running into now.

Comment: It is you are right. You should store the contents of the cookie on server side and add a validation to your app that only allowed users are able to access to domains contents even if they are logged in.